# Visual Studio Narrow bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

What is the name of the narrow bar in vs environment showing all line of document?
([as you can see in pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Itv8.png))
And how can i hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is: "Map mode for vertical scroll bar"

Mode for vertical scroll bar is at: *'Tools' Menu -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars -> Behavior*

To hide the Map, select: "Use bar mode for scroll bar"

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

I just found if

```
options > Text Editor > All languages > Scroll Bars
```